# Getting error selectpicker is not a function for bootstrap-select on a new Rails 6 application with webpacker

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker, bootstrap-select

I have a new rails 6 application with webpacker, jquery, bootstrap and bootstrap-select(https://yarnpkg.com/package/bootstrap-select).

**Configuration:**

Here is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "report_machine",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "4.2.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "bootstrap-select": "^1.13.17",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  }
}
```

`app/javascript/pack/application.js`

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

import "bootstrap"
import("bootstrap-select")

require('custom/datepicker')
import "../stylesheets/application"
```

`config/webpack/environment.js`

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require("webpack")

environment.plugins.append("Provide", new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
  Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
  Selectpicker: 'bootstrap-select'
}))

module.exports = environment
```

and `application.html.erb`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>ReportMachine</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.13/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

ajax call:

```
$(".country-select").change(function(){
    var country = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/reports/providers_filter",
        method: "GET",  
        dataType: "json",
        data: {country: country},
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.error('AJAX Error: ' + status + error);
        },
        success: function (response) {
            var tasks = response["providers"];
            $(".providers-select").empty();

            for(var i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++){
                $(".providers-select").append('<option value="' + tasks[i]["id"] + '">' +tasks[i]["slug"] + '</option>');
            };

            $(".providers-select").selectpicker();      

        }
    });
});
```

**Error:**

On the dev console as well as on the success function of ajax call I get

**`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).selectpicker is not a function`**

Can you please point out if I have some issue with my configuration or am I missing something.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you including bootstrap and bootstrap-select both in webpack and via CDN?

Comment: @rossta   I am using CDN to import css only not JS.

Comment: Have you tried requiring `bootstrap-select` instead importing it, like: `require ("bootstrap-select")`

Answer (score 2):

I've met the same problem in my rails 5 applications.
I added a line at /app/javascript/packs/application.js.

```
require('bootstrap-select/js/bootstrap-select')
```

It works for me.
Hope it's helpful.